# ExtJS Pivot Grid Left-Axis height different than data-cell height

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying out ExtJS Pivot Grid. I'm using the examples pretty much as-is from examples (here: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3-beta1-6976/examples/pivotgrid/people.html ) except I'm putting the grid in a layout so that I can have another grid below it.

What seems to be happening is the Left-Axis grid 'stretches' vertically to fill in its portion of the layout (using vbox layout), but the cell with the pivot data isn't stretching so the rows aren't lined up.

Anyone else have this problem?  Is their a viewconfig or something I can set to tell all rows (left-axis and data) to stretch vertically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change de doctype to

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: Worked!  I'm a bit confused 'why' it worked though.  How does this line fix it?

Comment: I'm changed doctype but problem remained still.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution!
You can opend ext-all.css and to find necessary height value in definition of `.x-pivotgrid .x-grid3-row-headers table td`.

For example in FireFox Gecko(Linux):

```
.ext-gecko .x-pivotgrid .x-grid3-row-headers table td {
    height: 22px; //original value - 21
}
```

For opera You can add style :

```
.ext-opera .x-pivotgrid .x-grid3-row-headers table td {
    height: 21px;//original value 18
    padding: 2px 7px 0 0;
    text-align: right;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: tahoma;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As this feature is, as of today, not available in a production release of Ext (3.3. is still only an RC), I'd highly suggest posting this in the Ext forums where one of the framework devs is much more likely to see it.